# Using several if statements to generate syntax required for command

Tags: bash

I'm writing a series of scripts to assist with the use of "doctl." Doctl is a CLI to the DigitalOcean API (https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl) which can, with the correct syntax and/or scripting to create that syntax, be extremely useful to DigitalOcean customers.
I have a way that works to complete the task at hand, but I can't shake the feeling that there's a better way to write the following function in bash.

The problem/request can be found in the ssh_public_ipv4 function as well as the ssh_private_ipv4 function. You'll see as you go down through the code that the lines for the if statements get longer and longer.

Below is the entire code for the particular script. Once I've completed the series of scripts I call "easy-doctl" I will release them to the public via my github page. https://github.com/hyukishi

I have a series of if statements to provide the syntax required for the function to execute properly based on the input provided by the user. There has to be a "short hand" way to write this out and get the same results.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Created by Jeffery Grantham 02/12/2019

doctl="$(command -v doctl)"
input="$1"
a1=""
a2=""
a3=""
a4=""
a5=""

# Array Function
droplet_id(){
n=0
for i in $(doctl compute droplet list --format ID)
do  ((n=n+1))
    if [[ "$i" == "ID" ]]; then
    ((n=n-1))
    fi
echo "$i" >/dev/null 2>&1
droplet[$n]=$i
done
}

while [[ "$input" != "quit" ]];
do
    clear
    echo "What would you like to do?"
    echo "1: SSH via PublicIPv4"
    echo "2: SSH via PrivateIPv4 (only for droplet to droplet connections)"
    echo "(Type quit to exit)"
    echo ""
    droplet_id
    read -rp "Enter the corresponding number and press ENTER: " input
    clear

# Functions
pause(){
    clear
    read -rp "Press ENTER to continue"
    clear
    return
}

ssh_public_ipv4(){
    $doctl compute droplet list --format ID,Name,PublicIPv4 | awk 'BEGIN{i=0} /.*/{printf "%d. % s\n",i,$0; i++}'
    read -rp "Droplet name or ID number: " a1
    while [[ "$a1" == "" ]] || [[ "$a1" == "help" ]];
    do
        $doctl compute droplet list --format ID,Name,PublicIPv4 | awk 'BEGIN{i=0} /.*/{printf "%d. % s\n",i,$0; i++}'
        read -rp "Droplet name or ID number: " a1
    done
    read -rp "User (leave blank for root): " a2
    if [[ "$a2" != "" ]]; then
        $doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-user "$a2"
    fi
    read -rp "Port (leave blank for 22): " a3
    if [[ "$a3" != "" ]]; then
        $doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-port "$a3"
    fi
    if [[ "$a2" != "" ]] && [[ "$a3" != "" ]]; then
        $doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-user "$a2" --ssh-port "$a3"
    fi
    read -rp "Path to SSH key (leave blank for default): " a4
    if [[ "$a4" != "" ]]; then
        $doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-key-path "$a4"
    fi
    if [[ "$a2" != "" ]] && [[ "$a3" != "" ]] && [[ "$a4" != "" ]]; then
        $doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-user "$a2" --ssh-port "$a3" --ssh-key-path "$a4"
    fi
    read -rp "Do you want to enable agent fowarding? (y/n) " a5
    if [[ "$a5" == "y" ]]; then
        $doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-agent-forwarding
    fi
    if [[ "$a2" != "" ]] && [[ "$a3" != "" ]] && [[ "$a4" != "" ]] && [[ "$a5" != "n" ]]; then
        $doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-user "$a2" --ssh-port "$a3" --ssh-key-path "$a4" --ssh-agent-forwarding
    fi
    clear
    $doctl compute ssh "${droplet[$a1]}"
    return
}

ssh_private_ipv4(){
    $doctl compute droplet list --format ID,Name,PublicIPv4 | awk 'BEGIN{i=0} /.*/{printf "%d. % s\n",i,$0; i++}'
    read -rp "Droplet name or ID number: " a1
    while [[ "$a1" == "" ]] || [[ "$a1" == "help" ]];
    do
        $doctl compute droplet list --format ID,Name,PublicIPv4 | awk 'BEGIN{i=0} /.*/{printf "%d. % s\n",i,$0; i++}'
        read -rp "Droplet name or ID number: " a1
    done
    read -rp "User (leave blank for root): " a2
    if [[ "$a2" != "" ]]; then
        $doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-user "$a2" --ssh-private-ip "$a5"
    fi
    read -rp "Port (leave blank for 22): " a3
    if [[ "$a3" != "" ]]; then
        $doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-port "$a3" --ssh-private-ip "$a5"
    fi
    if [[ "$a2" != "" ]] && [[ "$a3" != "" ]]; then
        $doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-user "$a2" --ssh-port "$a3" --ssh-private-ip "$a5"
    fi
    read -rp "Path to SSH key (leave blank for default): " a4
    if [[ "$a4" != "" ]]; then
        $doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-key-path "$a4" --ssh-private-ip "$a5"
    fi
    if [[ "$a2" != "" ]] && [[ "$a3" != "" ]] && [[ "$a4" != "" ]]; then
        $doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-user "$a2" --ssh-port "$a3" --ssh-key-path "$a4" --ssh-private-ip "$a5"
    fi
    read -rp "Do you want to enable agent fowarding? (y/n) " a5
    if [[ "$a5" == "y" ]]; then
        $doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-agent-forwarding --ssh-private-ip "$a5"
    fi
    if [[ "$a2" != "" ]] && [[ "$a3" != "" ]] && [[ "$a4" != "" ]] && [[ "$a5" != "n" ]]; then
        $doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-user "$a2" --ssh-port "$a3" --ssh-key-path "$a4" --ssh-agent-forwarding --ssh-private-ip "$a5"
    fi
    clear
    $doctl compute ssh "${droplet[$a1]}" --ssh-private-ip "$a5"
    return
}

if [[ "$input" == "1" ]]; then
    ssh_public_ipv4
fi

if [[ "$input" == "2" ]]; then
    ssh_private_ipv4
fi

done
```

Like I said before, the script works perfectly as is but I feel like there is a "short hand" way to write the functions that would leave me with a much cleaner script. And before anyone says it, I use ssh from the terminal personally, but to be all inclusive of the functions of "doctl" I am including these functions. I'm just trying to solve the problem now before it continues further down the line through the consecutive bash scripts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really run `$doctl compute ssh` multiple times, or is the implication that you run it *once* with the appropriate arguments?

Comment: Once with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: Ok, then just collect them in an array as you process the user's input, then call `$doct compute ssh "${ssh_args[@]}"` at the end. Once you do that, you might find some way to combine `ssh_public_ipv4` and `ssh_private_ipv4` into a single function as well.

Comment: There's a problem with your approach to the issue. "${ssh_args[@]}" will print all of the array elements for ssh_args which will produce an error upon execution because unused arguments will produce an error.

Comment: That depends entirely on what you put *in* `ssh_args`. If you don't need `--ssh-user`, for example, don't add it to the array.

Comment: I don't think you fully understand what I'm asking for. I need ALL of the flags for this set of command to be included as options without the user having to manually provide the flag along with the information needed to fill the variable for that flag.

I.E. the user shouldn't have to put in "--ssh-key-file /path/to/keyfile" but rather just "/path/to/keyfile" and the flag would automatically be added to the syntax to perform the requested operation. The flag needs to be called if input is detected and otherwise ignored.

Comment: No, I don't understand (disclaimer, I'm not familiar with Digital Ocean's offerings). Are you saying you really need to run `$doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-user "$a2"` and `$doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-port "$a3"` separately, rather than a single command `$doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-user "$a2" --ssh-port "$a3"` after determining that both `a2` and `a3` are non-empty? And if, for example, the default user is really `root`, you can always use `$doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-user "${a2:-root}"` rather than omit `--ssh-user` entirely.

Comment: Correct. If an argument is provided (not empty aka null), the flag needs to be added to the syntax for the command in order to be read properly. The only problem with "`$doctl compute ssh "$a1" --ssh-user "${a2:-root}`" rather than omit `--ssh-user` entirely." is that it would still be passing flags with empty args which would then produce an error causing `exit 1`

Comment: `"${a2:-root}"` is not an empty argument; if `a2` is unset or null, the expansion produces the string `root`.

Comment: BTW, `doctl="$(command -v doctl)"` is generally a bad practice. It doesn't buy you any performance at all -- the shell caches PATH lookups on its own -- and it generates bugs (take the case where your `PATH` entry contains spaces as an example). Just call `doctl` and let the shell take care of the caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is to gather the necessary arguments in an array as you process the user's input. For example:

```
ssh_public_ipv4 () {
    while true; do
        $doctl compute droplet list --format ID,Name,PublicIPv4 | awk 'BEGIN{i=0} /.*/{printf "%d. % s\n",i,$0; i++}'
        read -rp "Droplet name or ID number: " a1
        [[ ${a1:-help} != help ]] && break
    done

    ssh_args=()

    read -rp "User (leave blank for root): " a2
    [[ -n "$a2" ]] && ssh_args+=(--ssh-user "$a2")

    read -rp "Port (leave blank for 22): " a3
    [[ -n "$a3" ]] && ssh_args+=(--ssh-port "$a3")

    read -rp "Path to SSH key (leave blank for default): " a4
    [[ -n "$a4" ]] && ssh_args+=(--ssh-key-path "$a4")

    read -rp "Do you want to enable agent fowarding? (y/n) " a5
    [[ "$a5" == "y" ]] && ssh_args+=(--ssh-agent-forwarding)

    $doctl compute ssh "$a1" "${ssh_args[@]}"

    clear
    $doctl compute ssh "${droplet[$a1]}"
}
```

If `a2` is left blank, the `--ssh-user` option isn't added to the array.

Some of the options with clear defaults can be added unconditionally by using the expected default. For instance:

```
read -rp "User (leave blank for root): " a2
ssh_args+=(--ssh-user "${a2:-root}")
```

The `${name:-default}` form expands to `$name` if the value is set and not null; otherwise, it expands to `default`.

Comment: That did it! One thing was missing which was to call the droplet array in the command syntax `$doctl compute ssh "${droplet[$a1]}" "${ssh_args[@]}"` and after that, the `$doctl compute ssh "${droplet[$a1]}"` was no longer needed. Thanks for the help @chepner!